# javafx loading detail for sql query execute

Tags: java, sql

i am working on javafx project and i want to create a loading sign on execution of my sql query but how could i know every part of execution of my query .

My code:

```
Thread df1=new Thread(){

    public void run(){

    for(int i=1;i<=1;i++){

        try{

            System.out.print("1%");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection  con=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sql541774","sql541774","password");
            String sql="Select * from messanger";
            Statement stm=(Statement) con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stm.executeQuery(sql);
            textmess.setText("");

            while(rs.next()){

                String sc=rs.getString(2);
                String sc1=rs.getString(3);
                String sc2=rs.getString(4);
            }

            rs.close();
            stm.close();
            con.close();

            System.out.print("100%");

            } catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
    }
};

df1.start();
```

it shows me output

```
1% 100%
```

how i will able to get true output like:

```
1% 2% 3% .........98% 99% 100%
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: In for loop  you have given the condition as i<=1 , so for loop executing only once.. And  why you have the database connection code inside for loop?

Comment: i am using to `Thread` in which i think loop is required .

Comment: and i want to know the real time sql execution in % or in integer which tell me that how much part of my sql has been executed

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with JavaFX. I removed the tags: please stop putting them back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First*: remove the for loop, its useless.

**Second**: You cannot do that. There is no way to know in advance how long your statement will take. This depends on things like how many data you request, the network speed, other statements executed in the same moment or how much other load is on the machine.

What you could to is the following (in **pseudo code**): Request how many rows are there in total and get row by row. On each row, you can increase the loading bar. You can split the loading bar by the number of rows or you can calculate how many rows would be 1%.

```
int numberOfRows = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MESSANGER;
for(i in numberOfRows)
    row = SELECT * FROM MESSANGER WHERE ID = i
    print i + " rows from " + numberOfRows + " rows loaded"
```

Comment: but this method is valid for only select query not for `update,delete,insert` what to do with that.

Comment: You can also do `update`, `delete` and `insert` for each row individually. But note that is could have an influence on the performance in which junks you perform your SQL.